# Dropbox Online Only Files Re-Downloading

Tags: file, download, directory, dropbox

I have folders flagged in Dropbox SmartSync as "Online Only" so that local copies of the folders' contents are not kept. Files in these folders are re-downloading overnight indicating that some process is trying to access files within these folders. I have excluded backup tasks and Trend Micro Antivirus as the cause.

Are there any Windows 10 Pro native applications that could be causing this to occur or is there some way that I can determine which processes have accessed files during a certain time period?

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation with closing processes and services related to backup and antivirus software tasks, I discovered that this issue was caused by Trend Micro Antivirus. Specifically it was resolved by adding an exception for folders in Dropbox flagged as "online only" so that routine antivirus scans excluded these folders and also disabling the service called "Platinum Host Service". I am advised by Trend Micro that this service is responsible for system optimisation tasks and that disabling it does not compromise virus protection.